# Filtering data shown on linechart in flex

Tags: apache-flex, filter, linechart

i am working on a line chart on flex which enable me to view the progress of data according to the year. I have tried using a slider to filter but it doesn't seemed to work. any help please?
i am not exactly filtering the dataprovider, but the alpha. My function will retrieve all the information from my array collection, but set the alpha to 0, so when user drags the slider, if the year falls below that particular year, it will display the data, which i then set the alpha to 100.

The data is there, the axis are all set, alpha is set to 0. but the problem is, it doesn't display the information line by line as what i wanted it to be, instead, it display the whole graph only until i drag the slider to the end...

these are my codes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
 <mx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
     import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

     [Bindable]
     public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {Year:"1990", Profit:2000 },
        {Year:"1991", Profit:1000 },
        {Year:"1992", Profit:1500 },
        {Year:"1993", Profit:2100 },
        {Year:"1994", Profit:2500 },
        {Year:"1995", Profit:1500 },
        {Year:"1996", Profit:1900 },
             ]);


                private function init():void {
                    expenses.filterFunction = sliderFilterFunc;
                    expenses.refresh();
                }

                private function sliderFilterFunc(item:Object):Boolean{
                        var result:Boolean = true;
                        pro.alpha=0;
                        if(item.Year<=slider.value || item.Year==slider.value)
                        {
                        pro.alpha=100;
                        return result;
                        }
                return result;


                }

  ]]></mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox horizontalCenter="0" top="10" horizontalAlign="center" height="100%">
        <mx:HSlider id="slider" minimum="1990" maximum="1996" value="220" liveDragging="true" change="init()" width="570" snapInterval="1" dataTipPrecision="0" labels="['1990','1996']" tickInterval="1"   themeColor="#000000" borderColor="#FFFFFF" fillAlphas="[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]" fillColors="[#000000, #000000, #FFFFFF, #1400D1]" height="48" styleName="myDataTip"/>
        <mx:Panel title="Line Chart with One Shadow">
        <mx:LineChart id="myChart" dataProvider="{expenses}" showDataTips="true" >
              <mx:seriesFilters>
                <mx:Array/>
              </mx:seriesFilters>
              <mx:horizontalAxis>
                 <mx:CategoryAxis
                      dataProvider="{expenses}"
                      categoryField="Year"
                 />
              </mx:horizontalAxis>
              <mx:series>
                 <mx:LineSeries id="pro" alpha="0"
                      yField="Profit"
                      displayName="Profit"
                 />
              </mx:series>
           </mx:LineChart>

           <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}" />
        </mx:Panel>
    </mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

sorry for the messiness.:(

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using dates as your x axis, the slider can "slide" between numeric values.

What I would do is make my expenses ArrayCollection to:

```
public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {Year: new Date(1990), Profit:2000 },
    {Year: new Date(1991), Profit:1000 },
    ...
```

Then for your filter function:

```
private function sliderFilterFunc(item:Object):Boolean {
    pro.alpha = item.Year.getTime() <= slider.value ? 100 : 0;
    return true;
}
```

Also, are you sure you want to set the alpha to 0 instead of just filtering out the data points? If you would like to shrink your ArrayCollection (don't worry this shrinks the ArrayCollection, not the source, the Array), you could just do:

```
private function sliderFilterFunc(item:Object):Boolean {
    return = item.Year.getTime() <= slider.value;
}
```

Finally, you should also set your own dataTipFunction for the slider so instead of seeing numbers they see the actual date.

Answer (score 1):

i created a Flex Library (DataFilterLib) that take care of all the filtering process, completly in MXML.
This library is free, you can find the project details there:
http://code.google.com/p/flex-datafilterlib/
If you want to have a look at the examples, they are all in the project's page (source available):
Check the examples online if you want to see how to filter on multiple criterias, using different Flex UI Components (CheckBox, Slider, List, ...).
Using these filters with a Slider (2-thumbs), you can easily filter your data and it will be automatically reflected on your Chart.

Thanks,
Fabien